# FluentAssertions BeEquivalentTo: Exclude missing members on expectation

Tags: c#, fluent-assertions

I'd like to assert that my dto (which is flat object with few properties) is equivalent to my entity (which is complex object with nested properties).

```
public class Dto 
{ 
      public string A {get;set;} 
      public string B {get;set;}
}
public class Entity
{ 
      public string A {get;set;} 
      public NestedObject C {get;set;}
      public string D {get;set;}
      public class NestedObject 
      {
             public string B {get;set;}
      }
}
```

| Dto | Entity |
| --- | --- |
| A | A |
| B | C.B |
| - | D |

If I try to do this:

```
dto.Should().BeEquivalentTo(entity)
```

it will throw an exception that Dto doesn't have "D" property. I don't want it to throw this exception.

```
entity.Should().BeEquivalentTo(dto)
```

this will not check nested objects and fail.

```
dto.Should().BeEquivalentTo(entity, x => x.ExcludeMissingProperties())
```

this will not throw an exception if dto have some property (for example, property "E") that does not map to an entity (entity does not have property "E"). I want it to throw an exception in that case.

How can I accomplish this?
Thanks.

Comment: It's unclear what `C.B` represents in your table. I recommend writing a more complete minimal example, in C#, including the class definitions.

Comment: Sure, I've updated the question

Comment: You might want to have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to see what a complete minimal example should include. For this question a _complete_ block of code that we can paste into an IDE and run would make it much easier to follow your question.